# Creating an ArrayList of unique items in an ArrayList

Tags: java, kotlin

I would like my code to create an ArrayList (uniquePinyinArrayList) of unique items from an existing ArrayList (pinyinArrayList) which contains duplicates.

The "println" commands do not execute (I think they should do when a duplicate is from the pinyinArrayList is found in uniquePinyinArrayList)

```
fun uniquePinyinArray(pinyinArrayList: ArrayList<String>) {
    val uniquePinyinArrayList = ArrayList<String>()
    for(currentPinyin in pinyinArrayList){
        if (currentPinyin in uniquePinyinArrayList){
            // do nothing
            println("already contained"+currentPinyin)
            println("uniquePinyin"+uniquePinyinArrayList)
        }
        else {
            uniquePinyinArrayList.add(currentPinyin)
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried

```
if (uniquePinyinArrayList.contains(currentPinyin)){
```

, though this also didn't work.

Edit:
This method actually gets run for each word from my list of source-words, and hence multiple ArrayLists are created. To fix this, I made a single ArrayList object for uniquePinyin outside of this loop. Things work as expected now!

Comment: To get back to the original question of why your code doesn't work - no idea, it prints the `already contained` statements just as expected for me.

Comment: Edited my question to explain why - oops!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `distinct()` function, it will do all of this for you!

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val listOfThings = listOf("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C")
    val distinctThings = listOfThings.distinct()

    println(listOfThings)  // [A, B, C, A, B, C]
    println(distinctThings)  // [A, B, C]
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html

Comment: Thanks, will use this to clean my code! However, I realised what the problem was and edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your array list to set.

```
 Set<String> foo = new HashSet<String>(pinyinArrayList);
```